# Read image and send it via socket - could not open file

Tags: java, image, sockets, image-processing

I am trying to write a simple server that uses sockets and reads images from disc when it receives http request from browser.

I am able to receive the request, read the image from disc and pass it to the browser (the browser then automatically downloads the image). However, when I try to open the downloaded image, it says:

```
Could not load image 'img.png'. Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file
```

The same goes for all other types of extensions (jpg, jpeg, gif etc...)

Could you help me out and tell me what am I doing wrong? I suspect that there might be something wrong with the way I read the image or maybe some encoding has to be specified?

Reading the image from disc:

```
    // read image and serve it back to the browser
    public byte[] readImage(String path) {
        File file = new File(FILE_PATH + path);

        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file); // try reading the image first
            // get DataBufferBytes from Raster
            WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
            DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
            return data.getData();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
        }

        return ("Could not read image").getBytes();
    }
```

Writing the data via socket:

```
OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
output.write(result);
```

In this case, the result contains the byte array produced by the readImage method.

EDIT: second try with reading the image as normal file

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
char buf[] = new char[8192];
int len;
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
while ((len = reader.read(buf)) >= 0) {
     s.append(buf, 0, len);
     byte[] byteArray = s.toString().getBytes();
}

return s.toString().getBytes();
```

Comment: Stupid question, why not just write the `File` to the `Socket`?  Right now you writing raw pixel data which is not in the format of a PNG file...

Comment: Are you sure that it didn't catch the `IOException`?

Comment: It did not catch any exception so it read the file. I tried also reading the image with FileReader and then convert it to byte array but the result is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use ByteArrayOutputStream, like,

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);
```

and then you can write to socket as,

```
 outputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
```